# Azure Blob Trigger Polling Consequence on Cost and Resources

Tags: c#, azure

I created a Blob Trigger on Azure (based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRztpy337kU&ab_channel=FrankBoucher) to watch for changes in files and process them if a new one comes in. When it runs locally I can see that it's polling every 2 seconds.

My question: Is this how it behaves on Azure? If so, what the consequences on $$ Cost $$ and $$ processing resources $$ if I'm only expecting a file once or twice a month?

Should I consider a different type of trigger to reduce cost and the use of polling resources?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You will be at least billed for the access of the polling mechanism to the storage account. Storage account operations costs are very low, but still.

A much more inexpensive and efficient way is using an [Event Grid Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid) that invocates the function once a blob is created. See also [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview)

There is a full sample that shows you how to create an azure function that uses the event grid to process new blobs. It can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event?tabs=dotnet)